# Can I activate php script with FTP batch file?

Tags: php, email, ftp, batch-file

I've written a daily batch file which uses FTP to login to my webserver and download a CSV full of new members using mget members.csv which is created on my site by PHP.

I've also have a php page on server which emails me with these new members. This php executes when I load the page in a browser but is it possible to execute it from the batch file?

I could also keep these members in a database if it's easier/securer but then ideally I wouldn't like to hold sensitive database login details in a batch file...

Many thanks

Comment: Are you talking about real batch files (OS specific), or do you have a PHP script doing the FTP login?

Comment: I mean a scheduled batch file on a windows machine, creating an FTP script which contacts the PHP on the host server. My crappy 1&1 package has ruled out Cron jobs so I need to execute the PHP locally

Answer (score 2):

Using a scheduled batch file under Windows you could use the [`start`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755674%28WS.10%29.aspx) command to execute a browser instance requesting the URL of your PHP script (which generates the email).

Put this in your scheduled batch file:

```
start www.stackoverflow.com
```

This one would use the systems default browser. To start a specific browser instead, you can use:

```
start /d "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox" firefox.exe www.stackoverflow.com
start /d "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer" iexplore.exe www.stackoverflow.com
:
```

You need to replace www.stackoverflow.com with the URL of your PHP script, of course^^

Comment: Thanks Jurgen I wasn't aware of that command! I could then either leave the IE page on screen telling them details of the download or presumably taskkill IE to clear screen. That would solve the security issue because no password would be required. Although in theory anyone could hit that script, I probably need to protect it somehow just incase

Answer (score 1):

Why not just setup a cron job to check every x minutes/hours for populated csv file and send you the file if it is populated?

[how to setup cron job](http://www.shayanderson.com/linux/linux-crontab.htm)

Comment: Thanks, I've posted multiple times asking for an alternative method but no one suggested that. 
These Cron Jobs sound ideal, I'll look in to setting them up as I've never even heard of them :p 
I have a basic hosting package with 1&1 and may need to download csvs to multiple clients ...Any suggestions?

Comment: Most shared hosting accounts I have used has a UI for creating cron jobs - just look for something like "Cron Job Manager" - you can create anything you need done in the PHP script and then just run the script with the cron job.

Comment: Also, if you can't add a cron job with your hosting account just setup a sceduled task (if using win machine) to hit the script URL every x minutes/hours

Comment: Thanks Shay, turns out I need to upgrade my package to £10 a month to get Cron Jobs - my boss won't be happy :p

Comment: Looking at free options - All our clients run Windows...Windows scheduled task hit URL scripts?? There isn't an option to key one in... I'll look in to it though